# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que dentro de un ciclo for, con valores tipo float, me muestre un tipo de secuencia diferente al que usualmente suele generar?

Tags: php, array, float

Tengo unos intervalos.
Ejemplo: 
[2;8)
[8;14)

Utilizo un ciclo for para realizar un conteo de los valores que existen dentro de cada uno de los intervalos.

```php
for($i=2; $i<8; $i++){

  echo $i; // 2,3,4,5,6,7 Valores que imprimirá mi variable i

}
```

La cuestión es que quisiera realizar un conteo con valores tipo float.
Ejemplo:
[0.2 ; 4.2)
[4.2 ; 8.2)

Utilizando el mimo ciclo for para realizar un conteo de los valores que existen dentro de cada uno de los intervalos.

```php
for($i=0.2; $i<4.2; $i++)
{
  echo $i; // 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2 Valores que imprimirá mi variable i

}
```

Valores que quisiera que imprimiera mi variable i
// 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9..... hasta llegar a  4.1(número que precede al 4.2)

Answer (score 3):

El tercer argumento del `for`, es algo que se aplica cuando se acaba un ciclo, no tiene porqué ser siempre "i++".

```php
for($i=0.2; $i<4.2; $i+=0.1)
{
  echo $i . '<br>';
}
```

Primer argumento: Se aplica al inicio.

Segundo argumento: Condición para permanecer en el bucle.

Tercer argumento: Se aplica al final de cada ciclo.

Comment: Gracias Francisco Garrido, te agradezco mucho tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo como aportación lo podrías hacer con `range` combinado con `implode` con una sola línea de código:

```
echo implode( ', ', range($first, $limit-$step, $step) );
```

Para automatizar, he usado variables, suponiendo que la lógica es la siguiente:

*Imprimir los valores entre `$first`  y `$limit-$step`, incrementándoles cada vez el valor de `$step`*.

Ejemplo:

```
$first=0.2; #Primer valor a imprimir
$limit=4.2; #Valor límite, restándole $step
$step=0.1;  #Valor que se incrementa cada vez
echo implode( PHP_EOL, range($first, $limit-$step, $step) );
```

**Salida:**

```
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5
2.6
2.7
2.8
2.9
3
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5
3.6
3.7
3.8
3.9
4
4.1
```

---

`range` te crea un array, y puede ser interesante por ejemplo si quieres retornar el resultado a otra parte del código para usarlo allí.

Por ejemplo:

```
$mRange=range($first, $limit-$step, $step);
print_r($mRange);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.2
    [1] => 0.3
    [2] => 0.4
    [3] => 0.5
    [4] => 0.6
    [5] => 0.7
    [6] => 0.8
    [7] => 0.9
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1.1
    [10] => 1.2
    [11] => 1.3
    [12] => 1.4
    [13] => 1.5
    [14] => 1.6
    [15] => 1.7
    [16] => 1.8
    [17] => 1.9
    [18] => 2
    [19] => 2.1
    [20] => 2.2
    [21] => 2.3
    [22] => 2.4
    [23] => 2.5
    [24] => 2.6
    [25] => 2.7
    [26] => 2.8
    [27] => 2.9
    [28] => 3
    [29] => 3.1
    [30] => 3.2
    [31] => 3.3
    [32] => 3.4
    [33] => 3.5
    [34] => 3.6
    [35] => 3.7
    [36] => 3.8
    [37] => 3.9
    [38] => 4
    [39] => 4.1
)
```

Es decir, `$mRange` es un array como cualquier otro, y lo puedes leer con `implode`, con un bucle, o sacar valores específicos de él por su índice.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias A. Cedano eso era lo que estaba buscando.